# Websockets plugins with node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am developing a application using websockets and wish to use node.js for the backend. I googled and found out that node doesn't supports websockets natively and hence plugins are needed.

I zeroed in on the socket.IO
Are there better options available? Further, is it safe to use socket.IO?

Answer (score 0):

There are other options like sockjs but socket.io is more mature and has more information / active development.

Comment: Express does other things like giving you easy ways to do routes and template HTML CSS JS etc. socket does the web socket and fallbacks.